# Indexing in Pandas compared to dplyr

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I am a R/dplyr user who is switching to pandas. I noticed that a lot of books on pandas focus heavily on the index. I have not seen such intense focus on the index on R's dataframes. Life felt much more simple and easy. Does pandas' index play a large part on everyday data science tasks?

I looked around on the internet but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Any insight would be beneficial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Does pandas' index play a large part on everyday data science tasks?*: Not necessarily.

I love the syntax of R/dplyr but have recently had to do the majority of my development in pandas. I myself have successfully avoided indexes without much trouble. In fact, the only operations in which I consistently use indexes is to prep the input for [stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)(similar to tidyr::gather()) and [unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack)(similar to tidyr::spread()) functions.

It is very possible to avoid indexes altogether in Pandas by converting any indexed data you come across to columns with [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Nearly all pandas operations that require an index have alternative methods that do not require an index.

In addition to this, I suggest looking into pandas function "method chaining". Method chaining functions such as [assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) are built to feel very similarly to R/tidyverse pipe functions and I believe it's no coincidence that they are built to operate primarily on columns rather than indexes.

[Here's a great guide on method chaining.](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining)
[Interestingly enough, here's another chapter from the same guide about indexes.](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-3-indexes)

Comment: Whenever you use reset_index() remember to add drop=True unless you need the old indices as a new column

Answer (score 3):

Index is very important in `pandas`, for example

```
s=pd.Series([1,2],index=[0,1])
s2=pd.Series([1000],index=[0])
```

You can add it , since it will match the index to get the row match base on that.

```
s.add(s2,fill_value=0)
0    1001.0
1       2.0
dtype: float64
```